# Db2 and java11?

Tags: db2, java, db2-luw

Any rumors on when Db2 (LUW) will officially support Java 11? As of now, the officially supported version is 8:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0011932.html

Due to license issues, we are looking into moving up to Java 11, but I don't find much info regarding Db2 support for it.

Comment: Don't hold your breath. By the way, why do you need Db2 to support it? You're not obliged to use the JDK that comes with Db2.

Comment: For the driver, there's always a risk that something breaks with a newer JDK. At the other end, if JDK_PATH is changed to something else than the default and there's a need to open a PMR, I suspect that IBM will have considerations about that.

Comment: The server JDK is not involved in driver communications in any way, it's only for running Java routines. What JDK version is used on the client is completely irrelevant. If the JDBC driver (on the client) continues to run with Java 11 runtime (which it should) then you don't need to change anything on the server. What "license issues" does Java 11 resolve, by the way -- out of curiosity?

Comment: Admittedly I did a poor job explaning myself. We have a couple of functions written in java which runs on the server as well as in the application. As an example a function that removes diacritics from a string is used in a generated column which is indexed, as well as in the application (to transform the search argument). It is possible to compile them with different JDK's, but I would prefer not to. License issue is perhaps also a bad choice of word, I'm running out of space in this comment, see for example: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html

Comment: Db2 servers use the IBM JDK, not Oracle's, so Oracle support terms don't apply; the IBM JDK 8 will be [supported until 2022](https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/support/lifecycle/). Similarly, you can choose to use the same IBM Java runtime, [freely downloadable](https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/sdk8/), on the client. If you are entitled to support of an IBM product that ships with the IBM Java SDK (the official name), that SDK is also supported using the same channels.